# Corona and Priority Rights

Tags: pct, priority, corona

I made an application last year in my country, exact date is 10th April. I missed last date for PCT. In my country, some of time limits are extending because of Coronavirus situation. Has WIPO a similar procudure? Do i have a chance to still apply PCT? It is very important to me.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WIPO has not announced any modifications to deadlines for filing under the PCT.

WIPO announced, "processing of applications filed via WIPO’s Global IP Services has not been affected by the Covid-19 outbreak".
https://www.wipo.int/pressroom/en/articles/2020/article_0004.html

Here is a list of modified deadlines and other responses of IP offices around the world: 
https://www.worldtrademarkreview.com/brand-management/ip-offices-implement-measures-in-wake-of-coronavirus-crisis

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case that the WIPO has not announced any changes. However that does not actually answer the question. There is something called [restoration of priority](https://www.wipo.int/pct/en/texts/restoration.html) that you might use. It is not COVID specific but it does allow for missed deadlines in some cases. What really matters is how the countries you actually want to go into treat restoration of priority.